# C# TCP/IP client receives 0 bytes

Tags: c#, sockets, server, tcp

**Hi everyone, **

I'm working on a game server. After the client is connected to the server and the user clicks on the login button it should send a packet to the server.
after it sends the packet it start receiving 0 bytes... I'm clueless.

```
  public void SendDataToServer(byte[] data)
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer = new ByteBuffer();
        buffer.WriteBytes(data);
        m_Network.MyStream.Write(buffer.ToArray(), 0, buffer.ToArray().Length);
        buffer = null;
    }


    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (PlayerSocket != null)
        {
            if (PlayerSocket == null)
                return;

            int byteArray = MyStream.EndRead(result);
            m_CurrentBytes = null;
            Array.Resize(ref m_CurrentBytes, byteArray);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(m_ASyncBuffer, 0, m_CurrentBytes, 0, byteArray);

            if (byteArray == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("You got disconnected from the Server.");
                PlayerSocket.Close();
                return;
            }

            m_ShouldHandleData = true;

            if (PlayerSocket == null)
                return;
            MyStream.BeginRead(m_ASyncBuffer, 0, 8192, OnReceive, null);
        }
    }
```

The server does receive the packet. this is my current packet

```
    public void SendLoginPacket()
{
    int ID = int.Parse(m_InputField.text);

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = new ByteBuffer();
    byteBuffer.WriteInteger(1200); //Test login packet ID
    byteBuffer.WriteFloat(12); //Test if it receives
    m_Network.m_ClientSendData.SendDataToServer(byteBuffer.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you go through Stephen Cleary's excellent series on this: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, no one can tell you what the problem is. That said, receiving 0 bytes is normal, when the remote endpoint has called `Shutdown()` with the "send" option. This is how the local endpoint knows that no more data will be sent.